# Which preposition is correct with Stelle?

Tags: preposition

I have been told that "in" is incorrect here:

> Wir sind auch **in einer schlechten Stelle**, um einen Sturm zu erleiden.

and should be "an":

> Wir sind auch **an einer schlechten Stelle**, um einen Sturm zu erleiden.

But, if that is true, why am I seeing these sentences in DWDS?

> Sie sind **in einer besseren Stelle** wirklich.

> Dazu sollen auch die bisher damit befassten dezentralen Dienste wieder **in einer zentralen Stelle** zusammengefasst werden.

> Der Blitz kracht dreimal **in dieselbe Stelle**."

> Auch im neuen Pingpong-Spiel führen die Probanden den Schläger nach oben, indem sie die Aktivität **in einer Stelle** ihres Gehirn erhöhen.

> Zu schwierig ist danach der Wiedereinstieg **in die volle Stelle**.

> „Wir sammeln die Daten nur **in einer Stelle** im Haus, und da kommen sie nicht raus“, entschuldigt der Leiter des Städtischen Gesundheitsamtes Frankfurt, Klaus Schildwächter.

> Dafür kennen wir den Schmerz, wenn wir **in eine Stelle** getreten werden, die eigentlich nur Freundliches erfahren sollte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the examples you quoted just feel off to me as a native speaker. Native speakers do make mistakes, too ;) Or they use the language in an uncommon way. This applies, for example, to

> Sie sind in einer besseren Stelle wirklich.

> Dafür kennen wir den Schmerz, wenn wir in eine Stelle getreten werden, die eigentlich nur Freundliches erfahren sollte.

Others of the examples you quoted use "Stelle" with a different meaning. In addition to just "place" in general, "Stelle" can also refer to your job, your position of employment, so to speak. Think for example

> Sie sucht eine Stelle als Bürokauffrau.
> She's looking for employment as / for a position as a female office clerk.

"Stelle" is used in this sense in

> Zu schwierig ist danach der Wiedereinstieg in die volle Stelle.

"Volle Stelle" here refers to a full time position, maybe after working part time.

Still other examples are using "Stelle" to refer to an organisational "place"

> Dazu sollen auch die bisher damit befassten dezentralen Dienste wieder in einer zentralen Stelle zusammengefasst werden.

The services that handled something decentrally before are supposed to be combined again *into* a new, central organisational entity.

> Wir sammeln die Daten nur in einer Stelle im Haus, und da kommen sie nicht raus.

The health office is collecting the data only in one organisational entity in their organisation, and there they (the data) never leave again to be useful somewhere else.

So in general, to use "an" with "Stelle" is kind of the default case. But there are exceptions, and sometimes people just make mistakes or use the language in an unusual way.

Answer (score 0):

> Wir sind auch *in / an* einer schlechten Stelle, um einen Sturm zu erleiden.

#### Short answer

That's bad style, regardless of possible idiomaticity in substandard registers.

The other examples have no bearing because almost all of them can be explained by cognate prefixes of seperable verbs, eg. *einschlagen*, "der Blitz schlug dreimal [*e]in dieselbe Stelle [ein]", *einsammeln*, "Wir sammeln die Daten nur in einer Stelle."

Two preliminary notions:

- *anstelle* and English *instead* show the same variation, which sounds as if derived from French *en*, cognate to *in*. An obsolete English form *enstead* also exists. However, French shows the same variation, cp. *en lieu, au lieu de, à la place de*, in addition to *plutôt*, and earlier *ains, ainçois*, apparently from *ante and then some. That's too much to attribute the variation to regional and merely phonologic changes.

The similaraty of such particles is rather intractable, most definitely leading to historic confusion. So eg. *ante* has to compare with *an die*.

- *an* is related to latin *ante* "before, in front of" and rather proximal but in contrast to *in* and English *on* not really locative.

However, none of this is explaining the only relevant example, "Sie sind in einer besseren Stelle wirklich."